# How to pass an array to php from python script?

Tags: php, python, arrays, json

I am running a python script from my php:

```
<?php 

$command = escapeshellcmd('<path>/myscript.py');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;
?>
```

Now I am in the need to pass a bidimensional array of strings from the python script to the php page, but I am quite stuck. Of course, `$output` will contain a single string of the whole array. I also thought about json, but in that case I should convert the python array into a json string (this could be another question)....

Comment: You'll need some kind of interchange format that python can produce and PHP can understand. JSON seems like a nice standardized option, in my opinion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your array isn't too exotic, your JSON idea should actually work just fine. I built a little python script (`test.py`) to feed the php script (`test.php`):

test.py:

```
import json
print json.dumps([['a','b','c'], ['d','e','f']]);
```

test.php:

```
<?php
$command = escapeshellcmd('python test.py');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;
$arr = json_decode($output);
var_dump($arr);
?>
```

Comment: json_decode has a parameter to give you an associative array, like this: json_decode($output, true)            http://php.net/json_decode

Comment: Look at my (updated) answer: It has a bi-dimensional array in python and also in PHP.

Comment: btw, for me this doesn't work as expected with the single quotes around the letters, may need double