# Get python list in PHP

Tags: php, python, python-3.x

I am looking for a way to obtain a Python list and display it on my website using PHP.

I've checked out and tried many online help-requests so I was hoping someone would be able to explain to me what it is I am doing wrong.

My Python script scrapes a website and puts the result in a Python list.

What I am trying to achieve is the following:

- I want to display (a part) of the list on my website.

I've tried to accomplish this with the following code:

*PHP*

```
<?php

  $outputArray = [];
  $returnStatus;

  exec('python ./scrapeWebsite.py', $outputArray, $returnStatus);
  var_dump($outputArray);
  echo $returnStatus;

?>
```

Python:

`print(newsHeadlines)` -> returning a list like this: `['item 1','item 2','item 3','item 4']`

However, the array comes back as `array(0) { }` and the $returnStatus value is `1`.

Comment: Easiest thing to do would probably be to just dump JSON to disk from your Python script, and read that file from PHP

Comment: The output of your `exec` call is a string, not an array.  So store the result in a string, then use PHP to cut it and make it an array, if you must (hint, PHP explode).

Comment: How about going directly to python instead of trying to cobble PHP into the middle?

Comment: A better, no-file reply using JSON: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46226655/how-to-pass-an-array-to-php-from-python-script/46226755

Answer (score 0):

Encoding the list with JSON and writing it to a file on the disk, and then reading the file in PHP and decoding JSON did the trick. To ensure the web-data is up-to-date I'm using `exec();` to execute the python file.

If going full Python this is an option you could use.

To help others with a similar problem, this is the code I used:

**Python:**

```
myListJson = json.dumps(myList) #Encode our Python list into a JSON string

f = open("./fileName.txt", "w") #Open the file that we want to write to for write access

f.write(myListJson) #Write the JSON String to the file that we have currently open

f.close() #Close the file
```

**PHP:**

```
exec(python3 /path/to/file/script.py); //Will execute the python script, ensure the needed packages are installed on the **SERVER**.

$fileContents = file_get_contents("fileName.txt");

$decodedJson = json_decode($fileContents); //This will now contain your Array like any other PHP Array.
```

Thanks for the help!